# Python print loading "animation" while connecting to PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, psycopg2

(Would welcome tips on how to rephrase the title.)

I am using psycopg2 and asyncio. What I want to happen is that the user has some indication that the program is doing something. I have a fancy "\ | / -" animation, but for simplicity let's just say I want it to print a dot every second.

What I have so far:

```
import psycopg2
import asyncio


async def heartbeat(seconds):
    for sec in range(seconds):
        print(".")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def conn_test():
    conn_params = {"database": "testdb", "user": "postgres",
                   "password": "my_pw"}
    conn = None

    print("Attempting to connect to database...")
    while not conn:
        try:
            conn = psycopg2.connect(**conn_params)

        except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
            print(error)

        finally:
            if conn:
                conn.close()
                print("Successfully connected to database. Now closing connection...")
            else:
                print("Could not connect to the database. Retrying...")


async def main():
    t1 = loop.create_task(heartbeat(10))
    t2 = conn_test()

    await asyncio.wait([t1, t2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

What I get (if I purposefully prevent it from connecting)

```
.
Attempting to connect to database...
```

(until psycopg2's timeout.)

What I want:

```
.
Attempting to connect to database...
.
.
.
.
.
```

(etc.)

I tried `psycopg2.connect(**conn_params, async_=True)`, but that does not have the effect I want. I do get my dots, but since a connection object is returned, even if no connection could be established, the rest of my code does not work as intended. I tried looking into async psycopg2 a bit more. But that approach just seems to bring a lot of extra work with it. I just want it to connect asynchronously, but once a connection exists, my `execute()`s should definitely not work asynchronously.

Comment: `conn_test` doesn't await anything so it doesn't give anything else a chance to run until it's complete. You should consider using an asyncio-aware driver. That still probably won't get you the desired result, though. You may be better off using a separate thread or process to update the UI.

Comment: I tried ```conn = await psycopg2.connect(**conn_params)``` but then I just get ```object psycopg2.extensions.connection can't be used in 'await' expression```.

Comment: Right. psycopg2 is not an asyncio-aware library. You'll need to use a different library such as asyncpg.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll look into it.

Comment: *but once a connection exists, my `execute()`s should definitely not work asynchronously* - if what you wrote here is true, you won't be happy with `asyncpg`. Async is not something you can use for a small part of your program, like a helper thread, it's an architectural decision that affects everything.

Comment: Well to be perfectly honest, I am still quite new to all of this. I know basic SQL, but my colleague is helping me with the statements and such. I just execute them in my code.

The async approach is an integral part of the rest of my program. So the architectural decision is made.

What would be the consequences of executing statements asynchronously?

Comment: You'd need to put `await` in front of each.

Answer (score 0):

Following dirn's suggestion, I rewrote the code using asyncpg:

```
import asyncpg
import asyncio


async def heartbeat(seconds):
    for sec in range(seconds):
        print(".")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def conn_test():
    conn_params = {"database": "testdb", "user": "postgres",
                   "password": "my_pw"}
    conn = None

    print("Attempting to connect to database...")
    while not conn:
        try:
            conn = await asyncpg.connect(**conn_params)

        except TimeoutError:
            print("Could not connect to the database. Retrying...")

        finally:
            if conn:
                print("Successfully connected to database. "
                      "Now closing connection...")
                await conn.close()


async def main():
    t1 = loop.create_task(heartbeat(10))
    t2 = conn_test()

    await asyncio.wait([t1, t2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

This produced the desired result in this specific example. Now to see how this works with the rest of my program...

Comment: Please use `asyncio.gather(t1, t2)` instead of `asyncio.wait([t1, t2])` because awaiting `asyncio.wait()` without using its return value will drop exceptions silently. Also, you can replace the whole last top-level block with just `asyncio.run(main())`, which is the preferred way to run your async code as of Python 3.7.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Yea I just followed some Youtube tutorial where he put everything in a try. Should there still be a loop.close() somewhere?